# Handling bottom navigation bar on Windows 10 Mobile

Tags: xamarin, win-universal-app, xamarin.forms, navigationbar, windows-10-mobile

In my Xamarin.Forms app I have a button at the bottom. This button is hidden on a Windows 10 Mobile phone. Isn't there a setting were the size of my page is adapting to the available size? In such a case the height of my page would decrease if the navigation bar is shown, and it would increase if the navigation bar is hidden.

I saw solutions suggesting to programmaticaly hidding the navigation bar. E.g.

```
ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryEnterFullScreenMode();
```

Where should it be placed? I put it in the `App.xaml.cs` before `rootFrame.Navigate` in `OnLaunched`. If I run the app on my local machine it changed to fullscreen. On the mobile phone the navigation bar was hidden, but there remained a white area at the bottom.

Furthermore I tried

```
ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().FullScreenSystemOverlayMode = FullScreenSystemOverlayMode.Minimal;
```

but I don't see something different.

How should a developer handle the navigation bar without hiding the content beneath it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to fix the issue:

```
ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().SuppressSystemOverlays = true;
```

The result is that the navigation bar isn't shown when starting the app. The user has the possibility to show the navigation bar with a swipe up. Here the page automatically resizes as desired.

I put it in the `App.xaml.cs` in the `OnLaunched` method:

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

    // Do not repeat app initialization when the Window already has content,
    // just ensure that the window is active
    if (rootFrame == null)
    {
        // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
        rootFrame = new Frame();

        rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;

        Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e);

        if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
        {
            //TODO: Load state from previously suspended application
        }

        // Place the frame in the current Window
        Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
    }

    if (rootFrame.Content == null)
    {
        // When the navigation stack isn't restored navigate to the first page,
        // configuring the new page by passing required information as a navigation
        // parameter
        ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().SuppressSystemOverlays = true;
        rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments);
    }
    // Ensure the current window is active
    Window.Current.Activate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().SetDesiredBoundsMode(ApplicationViewBoundsMode.UseVisible);
```

In the App.xaml.cs file for UWP in the onLauched function like this:

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            this.DebugSettings.EnableFrameRateCounter = true;
        }

        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

        // Do not repeat app initialization when the Window already has content,
        // just ensure that the window is active
        if (rootFrame == null)
        {
            // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
            rootFrame = new Frame();

            rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;

            Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e);

            if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
            {
                //TODO: Load state from previously suspended application
            }

            // Place the frame in the current Window
            Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
        }

        if (rootFrame.Content == null)
        {
            // When the navigation stack isn't restored navigate to the first page,
            // configuring the new page by passing required information as a navigation
            // parameter
            ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().SetDesiredBoundsMode(ApplicationViewBoundsMode.UseVisible);
            rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments);
        }
        // Ensure the current window is active
        Window.Current.Activate();
    }
```

This will make sure your app stays inside the visible area, thus with no overlay from the bottom navigation bar.